# Error when decompiling MCP 9.40

Tags: minecraft

I'm trying to decompile MCP 9.40 for Minecraft 1.12. But when I run decompile.bat it returns the following error.

https://hastebin.com/itefigucaz.bash

I have looked around and found that it may be that the decompiler running out of RAM, so I edited the mcp.cfg file and changed one line from this.

```
CmdFernflower = %s -jar %s -din=1 -rbr=1 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -rsy=1 -iec=1 -jvn=1 -log=WARN {extra} {indir} {outdir}
```

To this.

```
CmdFernflower = %s -Xms2G -jar %s -din=1 -rbr=1 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -rsy=1 -iec=1 -jvn=1 -log=WARN {extra} {indir} {outdir}
```

But it yields the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that apparently the decompiler doesn't run correctly with to much RAM, so instead I change it to 1 GB by editing the line to this.

```
CmdFernflower = %s -Xmx1G -jar %s -din=1 -rbr=1 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -rsy=1 -iec=1 -jvn=1 -log=WARN {extra} {indir} {outdir}
```